# Android send null parameter when post json to webservice

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, httpurlconnection

Please help me, i'm having trouble sending POST request with JSON-object as parameter body using HttpUrlConnection class. i've been looking around in SO for the same question, i've tried the solution but none of them work for my case. This is my code (i call this method in AsyncTask-class):`

```
 public JSONObject postData(String url, JSONObject params) throws IOException{
    JSONObject ret=null;
    OutputStream os=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    HttpURLConnection cnHost=null;
    URL host=null;
    String jsStr=null;
    StringBuilder result=null;
    String json="";

    try {

        //TODO Open host connection
        host = new URL(url);
        jsStr = "key="+params;
        cnHost = (HttpURLConnection) host.openConnection();

        //TODO set request Attribute
            //Set Connection attributes
            cnHost.setDoInput(true);
            cnHost.setDoOutput(true);
            cnHost.setUseCaches (false);
            cnHost.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            cnHost.setReadTimeout(10000);
            cnHost.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            cnHost.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
            cnHost.setRequestMethod("POST");

        //TODO Start streaming request
        cnHost.connect();

        os =cnHost.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
        wr.write(jsStr);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        //TODO get Response
        try {
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(cnHost.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line); }

                //TODO cast to json Object
                json = result.toString();
                in.close();
                reader.close();

                ret = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Get_response","inner_Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Add IOException Handler
        Log.d("IOException", "Descp:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        //TODO Add NUllPointerException
        Log.d("NullPointerException","Descp:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        //TODO Add Exception Handler
        Log.d("Exception","Descp");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        //region Log postData (removed when no bug)
            Log.d("bodyContent:", jsStr);
            Log.d("RequestMethod", cnHost.getRequestMethod());
            Log.d("DoInput", String.valueOf(cnHost.getDoInput()));
            Log.d("DoOutput", String.valueOf(cnHost.getDoOutput()));
            Log.d("FixLengthStreamMode", String.valueOf(jsStr.getBytes().length));
            Log.d("Content-Type", cnHost.getRequestProperty("Content-Type"));
            Log.d("Response_Message",json);
        //endregion
        cnHost.disconnect();
    }

    return ret;
}   `
```

and below is my code calling the method above:

```
try{
    JSONObject jsParam=new JSONObject();
jsParam.put("method", URLEncoder.encode("check","UTF-8"));

JSONObject jsResponse=postData(myUrl,jsParam);
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace;
} finally{
    if(jsObj==null){
            Log.d("NullJson","Yes, jsObj return null");
        }  else {
            Log.d("ValidResponse",jsObj.toString());
        }
}
```

when this request Post from android-app, the web-service always response that said request-body contain is a null message. But when i send it using Postman-client, the web-service response with valid message. Below my Postman code:

```
POST /mro/public/index.php? HTTP/1.1
Host: mro.alfamartku.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 25463d97-b821-7016-d3e7-5e256d69a31a

key={"method":"check"}
```

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: It did not raise error on application. The app success post request to web-service, but it return invalid message (which is in my case then post body is null string) and give response said 'wrong method'. And my post body exactly the same (and right) according to API-documentation. I've already check & make sure then post doesn't contain new line feed character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL url;
URLConnection urlConn;
DataOutputStream printout;
DataInputStream  input;
url = new URL (getCodeBase().toString() + "env.tcgi");
urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setDoInput (true);
urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");   
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
urlConn.connect();  
//Create JSONObject here
JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
jsonParam.put("description", "Real");
jsonParam.put("enable", "true");
```

The part which you missed is in the the following... i.e., as follows..

```
// Send POST output.
printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream ());
printout.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8"));
printout.flush ();
printout.close ();
```

The rest of the thing you can do it.

Comment: After I've compared your code and Post-man client generate-code result . I've missed the part `.setRequestProperty("Host","someHostName");`. Thank's a lot your solution, it dit work for me.